# OutOfMemoryError - HazelCast v3.6.4

Tags: hazelcast

We're seeing nodes in the cluster hitting OOME every now and then. The logs from the machine (XX.XX.XX.187) which hit this issue recently is shown below. The communication problem between XX.XX.XX.187 and XX.XX.XX.184 (which is another node in the cluster) seems to be causing the problem but we're not very sure of it. Once the machine hits OOME, the Hazelcast is shutdown.

Following logs are of interest:

```
2016-08-28T10:30:44:715+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.operations.MasterConfirmationOperation WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000 has sent MasterConfirmation, but this node is not master!
2016-08-28T10:31:14:715+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.operations.MasterConfirmationOperation WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000 has sent MasterConfirmation, but this node is not master!
2016-08-28T10:31:44:715+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.operations.MasterConfirmationOperation WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000 has sent MasterConfirmation, but this node is not master!
2016-08-28T10:31:51:986+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Connection [Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
2016-08-28T10:31:51:987+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Removing Member [XX.XX.XX.184]:45000
2016-08-28T10:31:51:987+0200 - com.hazelcast.partition.InternalPartitionService INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Removing Member [XX.XX.XX.184]:45000
2016-08-28T10:31:51:988+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4]

Members [3] {
Member [XX.XX.XX.186]:45000
Member [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 this
Member [XX.XX.XX.185]:45000
}

2016-08-28T10:31:51:988+0200 - com.hazelcast.transaction.TransactionManagerService INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Committing/rolling-back alive transactions of Member [XX.XX.XX.184]:45000, UUID: 3fb9cff4-a33d-4ca1-b51d-6b387fbb0856
2016-08-28T10:31:52:497+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.SocketAcceptorThread INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Accepting socket connection from /XX.XX.XX.184:54655
2016-08-28T10:31:52:497+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Established socket connection between /XX.XX.XX.187:45000 and /XX.XX.XX.184:54655
2016-08-28T10:32:14:715+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.operations.MasterConfirmationOperation WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] MasterConfirmation has been received from Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000, but it is not a member of this cluster!
2016-08-28T10:32:14:718+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Connection [Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
2016-08-28T10:32:14:718+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.nonblocking.NonBlockingSocketReader WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-1 Closing socket to endpoint Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
2016-08-28T10:32:30:801+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.SocketAcceptorThread INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Accepting socket connection from /XX.XX.XX.184:34362
2016-08-28T10:32:30:802+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Established socket connection between /XX.XX.XX.187:45000 and /XX.XX.XX.184:34362
2016-08-28T10:32:30:812+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.operations.JoinCheckOperation INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Ignoring join check from Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000, because this node is not master...
2016-08-28T10:34:30:801+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.operations.JoinCheckOperation INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Ignoring join check from Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000, because this node is not master...
2016-08-28T10:36:30:800+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.operations.JoinCheckOperation INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Ignoring join check from Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000, because this node is not master...
2016-08-28T10:38:30:802+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.operations.JoinCheckOperation INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Ignoring join check from Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000, because this node is not master...
2016-08-28T10:38:30:845+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Connection [Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
2016-08-28T10:38:30:845+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.nonblocking.NonBlockingSocketReader WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-1 Closing socket to endpoint Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
2016-08-28T10:38:36:857+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4]

Members [4] {
Member [XX.XX.XX.186]:45000
Member [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 this
Member [XX.XX.XX.185]:45000
Member [XX.XX.XX.184]:45000
}

2016-08-28T10:38:36:857+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Connecting to /XX.XX.XX.184:45000, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
2016-08-28T10:38:36:858+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Established socket connection between /XX.XX.XX.187:58928 and /XX.XX.XX.184:45000
......
....
2016-08-28T23:07:44:727+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Ignoring heartbeat from Member [XX.XX.XX.186]:45000 since it is expired (now: Sun Aug 28 23:07:47 CEST 2016, timestamp: Sun Aug 28 23:05:12 CEST 2016)
2016-08-28T23:07:44:727+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Ignoring heartbeat from Member [XX.XX.XX.186]:45000 since it is expired (now: Sun Aug 28 23:07:47 CEST 2016, timestamp: Sun Aug 28 23:05:07 CEST 2016)
2016-08-28T23:07:45:056+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Ignoring heartbeat from Member [XX.XX.XX.186]:45000 since it is expired (now: Sun Aug 28 23:07:48 CEST 2016, timestamp: Sun Aug 28 23:05:17 CEST 2016)
2016-08-28T23:07:52:793+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] System clock apparently jumped from 2016-08-28T23:05:03.295 to 2016-08-28T23:07:52.792 since last heartbeat (+164497 ms)
2016-08-28T23:07:52:794+0200 - com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Resetting heartbeat timestamps because of huge system clock jump! Clock-Jump: 164497 ms, Heartbeat-Timeout: 300000 ms
2016-08-28T23:09:34:960+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Connection [Address[XX.XX.XX.185]:45000] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
2016-08-28T23:09:34:960+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Connection [Address[XX.XX.XX.186]:45000] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
2016-08-28T23:09:34:961+0200 - com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Connection [Address[XX.XX.XX.184]:45000] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
2016-08-28T23:09:34:962+0200 - com.hazelcast.instance.Node WARNING: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Terminating forcefully...
2016-08-28T23:09:34:962+0200 - com.hazelcast.instance.Node INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Shutting down connection manager...
2016-08-28T23:09:34:963+0200 - com.hazelcast.instance.Node INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Shutting down node engine...
2016-08-28T23:09:35:291+0200 - com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Destroying node NodeExtension.
2016-08-28T23:09:35:291+0200 - com.hazelcast.instance.Node INFO: [XX.XX.XX.187]:45000 [dev] [3.6.4] Hazelcast Shutdown is completed in 329 ms.
```

The OutOfMemoryException is caused by NonBlockingSocketWriter.writeQueue which grows to consume around 6GB.

Could some one please go through the logs and suggest what might be causing this issue? Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to sync clocks of the machine, for example using NTP. If you already doing that, what's the system load on each of the machines. You might have a GC problem which means the JVm stops too long and the heartbeat is ignored for that reason and maybe the member is already considered dead which causes the reconnect.

Comment: The machine clocks are synced. You're right in guessing that GC problem is causing the JVM to stop which in turn results in missing heartbeats. So, we're mainly interested in debugging the GC problem which seems to caused by Hazelcast's NonBlockingSocketWriter. The heap dump analysis shows that the field 'writeQueue' of NonBlockingSocketWriter is growing too big which is causing OOM error.
I'll be posting further comments and updates at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8827

Answer (score 0):

Let's track it on github. It does not make sense to post separate answers on groups, stack-overflow and github...

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8827